# Port forwarding with two routers and two machines

Tags: networking, home-networking, port-forwarding, nat

I am having issues with a specific game regarding `restrictive NAT`. The game is AOE online. When I try to play online matches I get a message regarding having a restrictive NAT and can not play. I have read the following instructions: [here](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/connecting/nat-type-strict).. I do not know if I am able to port forward specific ports as both PC's listed below are looking to play this game on the same network.

My set-up at home is as follows:

### Router1 (Netopia 2247-02)

- Connected to internet directly (ADSL)
- IP: 192.168.1.1
- DHCP: ON - from 192.168.1.11 to 192.168.1.25
- UPnP: ON
- Firewall: OFF

### Router2 (Linksys WRT54g -  DD-WRT v24 RC-5 (11/22/07) micro)

- Connected to `Router1` via LAN.
- IP: 192.168.1.2
- DHCP: OFF
- UPnP: ON
- Firewall: OFF

### PC1

- IP: Static - 192.168.1.10
- Connected to `Router2` via LAN.

### PC2

- IP: Dynamic - coming from `Router1` - 192.168.1.20
- Connected to `Router2` via LAN.

What can I do to remove this restrictive NAT issue when I have two PC's trying to play the same game on the same network/router?

Thanks in advance.

### Update

If I connect `PC1` directly to `Router1` and port forward to that IP address i.e. `192.168.1.10` it does work.

### Network Diagram

[image]

Comment: You might want to add Router2 to the DMZ in Router1, so you only have one level of NAT (is there a a reason you need NAT and DHCP on Router1?)

Comment: I added `Router2` as static NAT on `Router1` (There is no DMZ option from what I can tell on that router). There is a third and fourth PC connecting to `Router1` so I left DHCP on that as they aren't connecting to `Router2` and have dynamic IPs.

Comment: What is the routing mode on Router 2? It should be bridge mode.

Comment: Have you opened the 7 ports as described in [this article](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Netopia/2247-02/Age_of_Empires_Online.htm)?

Comment: @JohnSiu Router2 is in bridge mode.

Comment: (1) Is PC2 the only having problem or both? (2) If only PC2 has problem, can you try plugging both PC1 and PC2 to router 1 and play at the same time?

Comment: @JohnSiu (1) Both `PC1` and `PC2` are having the problem. Even on their own when one or the other is switched off. (2) Unfortunately that's not an option due to the layout of the house. There's only one LAN cable running to `Router2`. `Note:` If I connect `PC1` directly to `Router1` and port forward to that IP address i.e. `192.168.1.10` it does work.

Comment: (1) OK, then the issue is actually router 1 (2) you can plug the router 2 cable directly to PC2, but it is not important now. We have to fix router 1.

Comment: For route 1, is it a adsl modem(phone line go into it) also?

Comment: Could you look at my link above and do the port forwarding as it is described there, without specifying an internal IP? The article seems to imply that this works on the Netopia.

Comment: @JohnSiu Yes the phone line is connected directly to `Router1`.

Comment: @harrymc I have previously tried the information on this site before posting on SO. Also, the problem here is the correct article is actually: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Netopia/2247-62/Age_of_Empires_Online.htm Please note at the end of that article it says: `"Use the Select Host Device box to choose a computer to forward ports to. This box contains a list of computer names that are visible on your network."` This is a problem as I have two machines that need these ports opened/forwarded.

Comment: There is a lot of information you haven't told us. A router has at least 2 interfaces (and 2 addresses!) - at least 1 "WAN" and 1 or more "LAN". Tell us what is plugged where, and both addresses. Also, what is your modem doing? It might be a modem/router and also doing NAT!

Comment: You need to turn off UPnP in router 2.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have tried it with UPnP on/off on `Router2`

Comment: @HughAllen I have added a network diagram to hopefully answer any outstanding questions.

Comment: This might be a coincidence, but I've had some port forwarding problems too when using dd-wrt as just a switch (WAN unplugged, no DHCP or UPnP etc.). Can you try re-flashing the original firmware? And your diagram and question still say UPnP is enabled on router 2 - it should be disabled if it's not doing NAT (which it isn't if its WAN port is unplugged).

Comment: @Seany84: Don't try with configurations that aren't supposed to work. It's counter-productive. What will happen is you'll have everything right but one thing, try a configuration that's not supposed to work, and it won't work because of the thing was wrong before, and now you have two things wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you will need to change some ports on one of the computers so you could port-forward these changed ports to that computer. The options I see are:

1. Use [Port triggering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_triggering) rather than forwarding, if supported by the Netopia
2. Use a VPN service that allows port-forwarding
3. Change the ports for Games for Windows Live, as described in the [Port override](http://www.microsoft.com/games/en-us/support/pages/troubleshootingissues.aspx) section.
   To summarize: Registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Software\Microsoft\XLive`,
   new DWORD `LivePortOverride` with value between 5000 and 65535.

I believe that UPnP should stay enabled on your router.

Comment: I like the look of point 3. I have created a registry entry,`LivePortOverride`, on `PC1` - value: 5050. What should my next steps be? Should UPnP be enabled on `Router1` or `Router2` or both? thanks a lot

Comment: I went with option 3 and changed the port it runs on my machine. This works on my machine at least as I haven't been able to do it on the other PC yet (room-mates PC). All I need to do is set it up on the other PC and it should be sorted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling UPnP on router 2. I used a similar setup and had to disable ALL active functions of the second router to successfully do what you are doing (use the second router as an unmanaged switch).

Comment: Still getting a restrictive NAT message when UPNP is disabled on Router2.